# JOGL com.jogamp.graph.curve.opengl.TextRenderer is missing?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, textrenderer

I am trying to look into the curve implementation of the JOGL TextRenderer class. According to [a post by mr Goethel](http://forum.jogamp.org/Which-JOGL-TextRenderer-should-I-use-td3199861.html) it is a better alternative to the awt implementation. 
It appears, however, that this new TextRenderer is missing from JOGL. It is supposed to be in the same region as [this](https://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/index.html?com/jogamp/graph/curve/opengl/RenderState.html).
Does anyone know if this feature is deprecated, removed etc?

From looking into it, there doesn't appear to have been announcements to remove the class, but there was some activity on the github repository [graph/curve/opengl](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/tree/master/src/jogl/classes/com/jogamp/graph/curve/opengl) recently.

Thank you very much for your help.

Edit:
Sven Goethel pointed me to an implementation of awt TextRenderer. [This blob](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl-demos/blob/9e1e4e8946c4f8089234a5788c0bee14ee2d0ff1/src/demos/j2d/TestTextRenderer.java) works perfectly without messing. But bear in mind, speaking as an openGL noob, don't forget to unbind any programs or other stuff prior to rendering text.

```
gl.glUseProgram(0);
gl.glBindVertexArray(0);
//etc...
//do textrendering stuffs
```

Comment: You should contact Sven on our official IRC channel. I haven't found this class, I have just looked at the changelogs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have gotten a few ideas from sven and I am looking at the demos in the git as suggested by himself. With respect to my question, it is 'in the works' as seen in [link](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/SW_Tracking_Report_Objectives_for_the_release_2.3.0#Graph). One warning Sven noted, the awt textrenderer is buggy, for example, I tried [rendering the letter 'e'](http://prntscr.com/6byj70)

Comment: I apologise for above, the weird output was due to an incorrect binding. [tada](http://prntscr.com/6bz4d5)